# Sync SharePoint On-Prem Files to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, synchronisation

I have SharePoint On-premise and SharePoint Online on Cloud on both sites I am storing many documents on daily basis.

My main goal is to sync everything is on SharePoint on-premise to SharePoint online on the cloud.

I want to know if the above is feasible, and what is the tool that should be used to do this synchronization?

Could you please provide resources if someone already did that before?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools from market such ShareGate, AvePoint, Metalogix.
Another one it's Veeam Backup & Replication have module/product SharePoint Backup and Replication for OnPrem and O365. I think you can prepare backup onPrem (by schedule) and replicate to SharePoint Online.

If you looking for free tools you can check SPMT from Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Comment: Thank you for your response. So as I can see to achieve that kind of Sync we should use a third-party tool. The SPMT does not have the sync feature only it allows us to migrate because our requirement is to sync on daily basis.

Comment: as far i know SPMT have scheduling. I think you can investigate Veeam solutions for replications.

Comment: I will check Veeam. Is there any official documentation for the SPMT scheduling feature? If so, could you please provide the link?

Comment: I checked again SPMT maybe you are right but maybe this feature will be available on next releases maybe not. Veeam have really nice products. Anyway if you not found solution for this we can create some solution together on GitHub.